# enforce code so that a breakpoint can be set on a particular line even in optimized builds

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, breakpoints, compiler-optimization

I'm looking for a way to reliably create places where a breakpoint can be set no matter what optimization is active; for all platforms but especially for x64 and newer visual studios. It should require as less code to type as possible and produce as less overhead as possible.

Here's a whole [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/T87j3cYfP) of what i tried so far.

The only working example is something like the following, but i fear it might be just a coincidence. Also, it couldn't be put in a macro.

```
bool b1 = rand();
bool b2 = rand();

if (b1 && !b2)
    volatile int bh = true;
else if (!b1 && b2)
    volatile float bh = true;
else if (b1 && b2)
    volatile double bh = true;
else
    volatile bool bh = true;
```

Is something like this even possible, especially with global optimization turned on?

Comment: Try `SetLastError(0);`. Borrowed from [How do you prevent the linker from discarding a function you want to make available for debugging?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150102-00/?p=43233)